# Visual Studio 2017 Has Missing Connected Services

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-active-directory

I am not seeing the **Authentication with Azure Active Directory** connected services in Visual Studio 2017 as seen in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-connected-services-add-active-directory.  I am running version 15.4.4 with no pending updates.  Any idea how I can get that to show up?

[image]

Comment: Have you installed all the azure tooling?  Run the vs installer and go look for anything azure-y

Comment: Yes the Azure tooling is installed.

Comment: Is this a core project, or full framework?

Comment: Core but I've opened both types of projects and the results are the same.

Comment: Dunno, then. I checked and no repro for me. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah I've checked Visual Studio on 2 co-workers computers, one has it and one does not.  I have a full install of VS.  No idea how VS is decided to show that option.

Comment: Might want to open a connect with MS.